# How to control Excel column size in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, size, cell, activexobject

I have a function in Javascript that Exports data to a new Excel file. I'm using ActiveXObejct("Excel.Application") to work with Excel. After The Export of the data is done and I see the result, the data overflows the width of the columns. This is causing some of the data look cut in the table. For example if I have the data '1234567890' in a cell I would see '123456' or '######' in the cell. So how can I control the width of the columns to fit the data they contain?
This is a code example of what I'm generally doing:

```
var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var Sheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
for (var i = 0 ; i < DataArray.length ; i++)
    Sheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1,1).value = DataArray[i];
Excel.visible = true;
```

Comment: Posting the code that you are using would be helpful.

Comment: Posted a code example.

Answer (score 1):

After the loop:

```
Sheet.Cells(,1).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 20
```

will change the width of column A.

Comment: something is not right wit this line of code. Sheet,Cells(1,1) Doesn't have EntireColumn or ColumnWidth property.

Comment: It doesn't appear in intelli-sense but it is correct. However, maybe there is an additional requirement because you are running this from JavaScript. Someone else might advise you about the JS side.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find an answer.

```
Sheet.ActiveSheet.Cells('A:A').ColumnWidth=11;
```

This will change the width of the first cloumn.